# Validate Textbox by allowing only numbers and float using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have been trying to validate my asp.net text-box to accept only numbers and  '.' 
 For that I wrote a function with the help of [Internet](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/44pc78pj/) (sorry am new to jQuery)
**Jquery**

```
$('#<%= txtWidth.ClientID %>').keypress(function (event) {
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
});
});
```

It works fine ,but **Delete** and **Backspace** is not working.How can I enable enable those keys with numberkeys ? What are the changes I need to make ??

Please help this beginner..

Comment: Why not using an ```<input type="number" />``` ?

Comment: @Kirk, the code works for me just fine... Even backspace and delete.
What kind of input is the text box?

Comment: @Treast type="number" it allows letters in Firefox..so i dont wanna use it

Comment: @Catalyst please try it on Firefox

Comment: I just checked and yeah, didn't know about this.

Comment: @Catalyst okey ..Fine !!

Comment: @AlivetoDie yah its working !! Thank you so much..!!

Comment: @AlivetoDie Sorry to say, Its not working on old version Browser .How can we make this code browser compatible ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149869/discussion-between-kirk-and-alive-to-die).